# opposite method to disable output escaping in xslt

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [XSLT: How to convert XML Node to String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6696382/xslt-how-to-convert-xml-node-to-string)

Input:

```
<text> aabbabab  </text>
```

output:

```
&lt;text&gt; aabbabab &lt;/text&gt;
```

This is the opposite to Disable output escaping.

How can we achieve this in xslt.

Can some one help on this.

Thanks

Comment: I believe that this question is a duplicate or slight variation on other questions on how to serialize XML. Please see: (1) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6696382; and (2) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11620147

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See **[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11623265/36305)**.

In summary, the shortest solution uses a tiny extension function.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use Saxon extensions, try

```
<xsl:value-of select="saxon:serialize(text)"/>
```

If not, there are various posts that tell you how to write your own serialize() function in XSLT.